# Which characters must be escaped to obtain a legal SQLite string literal?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite

The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) states:

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL.

Obviously, this is not quite enough to implement a method that returns, for any input string `a`, an output string `b` such that one can safely interpolate it, without any further manipulation, into an SQL query such as

```
select * from names where name = $b;
```

It is clear that one step in getting from `a` to `b` is to replace each occurrence of `'` (single quote) by `''` (two single quotes), and that as last step, a leading and a trailing single quote has to be added. However, it is not clear how to treat critical characters like newlines, since the documentation just states that escapes are not allowed; it is also not clear which characters could cause problems.

**Note** I know one of the standard replies to questions like this is "don't escape, use parameter binding", which, as such is probably the right thing to do; however, I'm working with an interface that doesn't allow me to formulate SQL `values` tuples, so I have to come up with a solution myself.

Comment: newlines are not critical characters -- they are just a flavor of whitespace

Comment: do you have a source for that?

Comment: There is no SQL I know of where newlines will impact how a query performs or functions

Comment: I just tested with actual newlines and tabs between the single quotes and it functioned properly, inserting those characters into the database field.  The only character that might cause problems is an 0-byte code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";` is in effect, the only (Unicode) characters to be concerned about are the single-quote and NULL (U+0000).

If you want unicode escapes to be replaced by the corresponding characters, you can use SQLite's `json_extract` function.  Here are some examples:

Input:

```
select 'a
b'; 

select 'é';

select json_extract('"\u00e9"','$');
```

Output:

```
a
b
é
é
```

### NUL

Literal NULs seem to vanish at the sqlite3 command-line prompt, in the sense that:

```
select length('a' || 'x^@y' || 'b'); -- where ^@ stands for NUL
4
```

However, using a different input method:

```
 select ('a' || 'x�y' || 'b');
 ax�yb
```

Comment: The [char()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#char) function will also generate string characters from unicode code-point values.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with actual newlines and tabs between the single quotes and it functioned properly, inserting those characters into the database field.

The only character that will cause problems is an 0-byte code (i.e. NUL character).

According to [sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#quote):

> Strings with embedded NUL characters cannot be represented as string literals in SQL and hence the returned string literal is truncated prior to the first NUL.