# Providing sanitised input to SQLite from the command line

Tags: macos, sqlite, command-line-interface

I’m building a SQLite database and need to use the command-line (Zsh). First I create the table:

```
sqlite3 example.sqlite3 "CREATE TABLE example('first' TEXT, 'second' TEXT)"
```

Then I add some values:

```
sqlite3 example.sqlite3 "INSERT INTO example (first, second) VALUES ('one', 'two')"
```

So far so good, *except* I’ll be getting the true values from a user-provided source. Let’s say I had the following:

```
first_value="one o'clock"
second_value="two o'clock"
sqlite3 example.sqlite3 "INSERT INTO example (first, second) VALUES (${first_value}, ${second_value})"
```

This will fail due to the single quote in the variables. What I’m looking for is for input to be sanitised. The equivalent to giving the values as arguments and letting SQLite do the escaping. Something like:

```
sqlite3 example.sqlite3 "INSERT INTO example (first, second) VALUES (?, ?)" "${first_value}" "${second_value}"
```

But from my searches it seems the `sqlite3` doesn’t support that feature, which I find strange since it would mean it has no way to prevent injection.

One solution I thought of was to use parameter substitution to escape the single quotes:

```
sqlite3 example.sqlite3 "INSERT INTO example (first, second) VALUES('${first_value//'/''}', '${second_value//'/''}')"
```

Which works *for this case* but I’m concerned that is not enough for every situation.

Comment: There's https://sqlite.org/cli.html#sql_parameters but I suspect it has some of the same issues.

Comment: @Shawn As far as I understand, it does have the same issues.

Comment: This question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697887/which-characters-must-be-escaped-to-obtain-a-legal-sqlite-string-literal

Comment: @Zorgoth Thank you, but it’s not. There’s nothing there that’s better than the escaping already demonstrated in this question.

Comment: Sure, but it is an exhaustive answer. There are no other characters to escape besides the single quote and NULL, unless you are planning to deal with non-UTF-8 encodings.